# Pass value from scope variable into fcsa-number min option

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, scope

Using [fcsa-number](https://github.com/FCSAmerica/angular-fcsa-number) directive for validating numbers in input field.

I want to restrict one field to get only numbers greater than value in another field. Can anybody guide me what am I doing wrong? Is it possible to pass value of model.Value1 into fcsa-number directive?

Here is part of my HTML:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" fcsa-number="{ min: 1000, max: 1000000000 }" name="Value1" ng-model="model.Value1"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" fcsa-number="{min: {{model.Value1}}, max: 1000000000 }" name="Value2" ng-model="model.Value2" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a plunker, created from fcsa-number example plunker.
https://plnkr.co/edit/kLGeslO1ZhnHYHymNFZn

Answer (score 1):

Could you try the same with `ng-attr-*` directive.

So you should use below directive with expression.

```
ng-attr-fcsa-number="{min: {{model.Value1}}, max: 1000000000 }"
```

It will help you to transform evaluated value of `model.Value1` to `fcsa-number` directive like below.

```
fcsa-number="{min: 10, max: 1000000000 }"
```

Here is a plunker, created from fcsa-number example plunker.
https://plnkr.co/edit/kLGeslO1ZhnHYHymNFZn

Comment: Excuse me I don't understand. What exactly I have to try?

Comment: Perfect, It seems that it works. The only strange thing is, that in second case the number is not separated with comma after thousands. But when I save data on current view and than go to another a again back there are commas after thousands

Comment: And other strange behavior. when I set first value for example to 1000, min option for fcsa-number is set correctly and I can insert only numbers greater and equal to 1000 into second field. BUT than when I change first value to for example 2000 min option is not changed and so in second field I still can insert numbers greather than and equal to 1000 not 2000. Any advise please?

Comment: could you create a plunker please??

Comment: I added a plunker to my question. Sorry I mistakenly addet it also to your answer so please just ignore it.
To the plunker - there are 2 fields. Both are set to value 1500. But when you change Value1 for example to 2000, you will still be able to set Value2 to 1500. But Value2 shouldn't be lower than Value1.